# Converting Flash file for iOS with Adobe Air

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe

Is it possible to convert a flash button that I have on my site with Adobe Air to work in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert entire flash apps using http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html, but if you are converting a single button it's not going to be worth the hassle.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it's not as easy as opening the flash file in Adobe Air and converting the file?

Comment: Kind of. The converter takes a swf and outputs a iOS app, it really only works for entire Flash apps, not a single button.

Comment: I should have known it wouldn't be that simple. Thanks, Nathan.